# Howto make horizontal scroll with React Scrollama

Tags: reactjs

Is there any help for horizontal scroll story telling components. Is ReactScrollama is only for vertical not horizontal scroll ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can make horizontal scroll using css

```
.class-name{
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

or

```
.class-name{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```